# Typeahead Losing focus on typing in the input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

When I type a character and as soon as typeahead popup opens with matched elements, the focus gets lost from the input element. I have to manually set the focus back again into the input element. Why is this happening? FYI, I found a similar closed issue in here without any proper answer:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2598

I am not finding any solution to this. I am using **ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js** version. I created a plunker using the same libraries but in plunker everything is working properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to diagnose if you can't get it to repro in a plunker. Does the same occur with normal `<input>`?

Comment: No problem of blur with normal <input>. I tried debugging the typeahead library. Looks like focus gets lost when matched elements found and typeahead popup gets open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using of old version of **angular-block-ui v0.0.12** was creating the focus losing problem. Found an issue https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui/issues/37. Updating angular-block-ui version to v0.1.0-beta.3 or upper will fix the problem.